# Give access to add items only to admin created superuser

Tags: django

I did this CRUD app and I want to give access to add items in to the app only to 'the admin superuser' created before. Can anyone explain me how to do that?

Comment: post some code, show us what have  you done....etc make some effort when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

If the CRUD you built is an API, then you can use the `IsAdminUser` permission class

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

class WhateverApi(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    #your code
```

If it's not an API then you can make use of the following decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def superuser_check(user):
    return user.is_superuser

@user_passes_test(superuser_check)
def my_view(request):
    #your code
```